# SwiftUI Stack Offset changing on rotation leading to crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to implement an app where the user can swipe to the left and the right to go to a different horizontal ScrollViews. In my app I use GeometryReader to detect if the current active ScrollView should change. I didn't include that in this example.

I noticed that very strange things happen if the offset of the HStack is changing with an animation and the device gets rotated to landscape mode. Not only does the app crash, the phone becomes completely unresponsive, too!

I tried this on iOS 13.5 and with 13.6. iOS 14 doesn't even recognizes the simultaneousGesture (why's that?). I think the .offset causes the problem.

Does anybody have a solution? I couldn't find another way to implement what I described at the beginning but I'd like to know about easier ways.

Thanks!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var offset: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                Text("Test")  
            }
          .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture()
                          .onChanged{ translation in
                            print("triggered")
                            if(translation.predictedEndTranslation.width < 50){
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)){
                                    self.offset = -UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
                                }
                            }
                          }
                      )
                      
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                Text("Test2")
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture()
                                     .onChanged{ translation in
                                        print("triggered")
                                       if(translation.predictedEndTranslation.width > 50){
                                           withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)){
                                               self.offset = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
                                           }
                                       }
                                     }
                                 )
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2)
        .offset(x: self.offset)  
    }
}
```

Another example with .position used instead of .offset (works on iOS 14 but not below):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var offset: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        HStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)){
                        self.offset = 0
                    }
                })
                {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
                  
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5)){
                        self.offset = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
                    }
                })
                {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            } .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        }
               
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2)
        .position(x: self.offset, y: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code snippet is not crashing for me ..

Comment: And what about the second one? And which version of Xcode do you use?